# AngularJS: uncheck checkboxes with no ng-model attribute

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to uncheck all checkboxes when press some button. I need to do this on AngularJS (no jQuery). My checkboxes don't have `ng-model` attribute. How I can uncheck them?
My HTML structure:

```
    <li ng-repeat="channel in channelsList">
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-click="isChecked(channel.id)">
                <img src="images/checkbox-unchecked.png" alt="" class="unchecked">
                <img src="images/checkbox.png" alt="" class="checked"><span>{{channel.name}}</span>
             </label>
         </div>
    </li>
```

My `channelsList` is only an array of objects with 2 properties: `id` and `name`.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why are you not using `ng-model`?

Comment: Do you have boolean that tells you if your channel is checked? where?

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="channel.selected"  ng-click="channel.selected=!channel.selected" />` and when user click the uncheckall button reset all `channel.selected` property to `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind checkbox ng-model to a `_selected` property.
Please note that I use `_selected` and not `selected` in case your API would in a near future return a `selected` property that would collide with this one.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="SampleController">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="channel in channelsList">
             <input type="checkbox" ng-model="channel._selected" /> {{channel.name}} (id={{channel.id}})
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="uncheckAll()">Uncheck all</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.channelsList = [
     {id: 'c1', name: 'CNN'}, 
     {id: 'c2', name: 'BBC'},
     {id: 'c3', name: 'Discovery Channel'}
    ];

    $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.channelsList, function (channel) {
            channel._selected = false;
        });
    };
});
```

Here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/VPOjKMUVyrMpPfT9jLz3

Comment: Thank you. This should work, but `channelsList` is an array I get from the server and I want to keep it in the same state as it is on the server (without `selected` property). Or this is not important?

Comment: No it's not important, I added `selected: true` to channels I wanted to be already selected, Check out this new plunker without selected but a new `id` property that could be returned by server API : http://plnkr.co/edit/VPOjKMUVyrMpPfT9jLz3

Enjoy.

Comment: Please note that I replaced `channel.selected` in the new plunker with  `channel._selected` in case your API would in a near future return a `selected` property that should'nt collide with this one ;)

Comment: @DmitrijBurlaj Did the new plunker matches your needs ?

Answer (score 1):

### Two ng-ifs

If you really want to avoid ng-model you could achieve the same effect with... notice the checked attribute

```
<li ng-repeat="channel in channelsList">
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
                <input ng-if="isChecked(channel.id);" type="checkbox" checked ng-click="check(channel.id);">
                <input ng-if="!isChecked(channel.id);" type="checkbox" ng-click="check(channel.id);">
                <img src="images/checkbox-unchecked.png" alt="" class="unchecked">
                <img src="images/checkbox.png" alt="" class="checked"><span>{{channel.name}}</span>
             </label>
         </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Don't you thing ng-attr would be simpler?

Comment: Will not this solution be bad in terms of client's computer performance? I am thinking that AngularJS should permanently call the function from ngChecked or ngIf attribute to check if the return value is the same. Or this is not a problem?

Comment: the ng-if statement is evaluated each digest cycle in angularjs. if your isChecked is something like $http.get("/api/ischecked/"+id); or if its simply just returning a value it is ok.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't need an isChecked function. Instead, just set a checked property on each channel, and bind to channel.checked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you need but supposing you have an array of ids telling the ids checked like this:

```
$scope.channelsList = [
    {'id' : 1, 'name' : 'foo' },
    {'id' : 2, 'name' : 'bar' },
    {'id' : 3, 'name' : 'foo' }
  ];
  var checked = [1, 3]


  $scope.isChecked = function(id){
    return checked.indexOf(id) >= 0;
  };
```

You can put a button like:

```
<button ng-click="uncheckAll()">click</button>
```

And use it to clear your array:

```
 $scope.uncheckAll = function(){
    checked = [];
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I have exactly the same array of ids telling if ids checked. I can clear this array like you describe, but it will not change view, so checkboxes remain checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ng-click` and `ng-checked` attributes.